# Bash split JSON to blocks and replace string within each block

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, regexp-replace

I have a JSON file with the following content:

```
{
    "Text %s and %s": "Text2 %s or %s",
    "Here is \"Name %s\" and %s and %s": "Blabla %s and %s or %s"
}
```

I need a bash command with use of some `awk` or `sed` converting this content to the following result:

```
{
    "Text %1$s and %2$s": "Text2 %1$s or %2$s",
    "Here is \"Name %1$s\" and %2$s and %3$s": "Blabla %1$s and %2$s or %3$s"
}
```

So i need to replace each `%s` with indexed copy within each qouted block.
I tried some gpt generated code with no luck

```
awk -F'"' '                                                                                                         
  BEGIN { idx = 1 }
  {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
      if (i % 2 == 0) {
        gsub(/%s/, "%" idx++ "$s", $i)
      }
    }
    idx = 1
  }
  1
' my.json
```

Comment: Interesting but `awk` might not be the best tool for this task

Comment: what about perl ? `perl -pe 's("([^"\\]|\\.)*"){$i=1;$&=~s(%s){"%".$i++."\$s"}ger}ge' my.json`

Comment: @DmitryK. glad to help, added as an aswer

Comment: Can your quoted blocks contain escaped or doubled quotes, e.g. `"this \"is\" bad"` or `"this ""is"" bad"`? Can they contain newlines?

Comment: @DmitryK. You might be able to drive a screw in with a hammer. However, the result will always fall short of what would be achieved with the right tool, such as a screwdriver. The same would apply if you were to use the right JSON shell tool called `jq` instead of `awk` or `sed`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
perl -pe 's("([^"\\]|\\.)*"){$i=1;$&=~s(%s){"%".$i++."\$s"}ger}ge' my.json
```

How it works

- option -p : assume loop like -n but print line also, like sed (from perl -h)
- `s///` the [substitution operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#s%2FPATTERN%2FREPLACEMENT%2Fmsixpodualngcer)
- `()` and `{}` as delimiters because when balanced nesting is allowed
- `/e` modifier: Evaluate the right side as an expression.
- `/r` modifier: Return substitution and leave the original string
  untouched. (useful because [`$&`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$&) readonly and avoids using another variable)

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -F: -v OFS=: '
    {
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
            x=1; 
            while(sub("%s","%"x"$s",$i)) x++
        }
    }1
' my.json

{
    "Text %1$s and %2$s": "Text2 %1$s or %2$s",
    "Here is \"Name %1$s\" and %2$s and %3$s": "Blabla %1$s and %2$s or %3$s"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples please try following GNU `awk` code. Using function approach and using `match` function to use regex `([^:]*)(:.*)` which creates 2 regex capturing groups which we are dealing with later on for substitution for getting required output.

```
awk '
function substitute_S(element,      count){
   while(sub(/%s/,"&",element)){
     sub("%s","%"++count"$s",element)
   }
  return element
}
match($0,/([^:]*)(:.*)$/,arr){
  val1 = substitute_S(arr[1])
  val2 = substitute_S(arr[2])
  printf("%s%s\n",val1,val2)
}'   Input_file
```

Comment: Hello, would you please help to reopen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77007200/how-to-find-two-lines-of-strings-in-bash-with-awk-or-grep)? I suppose the OP's question is clear enough. I was about to post my answer when it was closed :( BR.

Answer (score 1):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
{
    "Text %s and %s": "Text2 %s or %s",
    "Here is \"Name %s\" and %s and %s": "Blabla %s and %s or %s"
}
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT=".";OFS=""}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=1){if($(i-1)!="\\"&&$i=="\""){cnt=0};if($i=="%"){$i="%" ++cnt "$"}};print}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
{
    "Text %1$s and %2$s": "Text2 %1$s or %2$s",
    "Here is \"Name %1$s\" and %2$s and %3$s": "Blabla %1$s and %2$s or %3$s"
}
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` to treat every character as separate field using field pattern (`FPAT`) and that field should be joined using empty string in output (`OFS`) to avoid superfluous spaces there. I iterate over fields using `for` loop, during that I set `cnt` to zero if current character is `"` and previous is not `\` and replace `%` signs with `%` followed by increased `cnt` followed by `$. When loop is done I` print` whole line.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Answer (score 0):

You could use a JSON processor like [jq](https://github.com/jqlang/jq) (which describes itself as "akin to `sed`,`awk`,`grep`, and friends for JSON data") to guarantee structural validity.

Here's one approach which defines a function that splits strings at each occurrence of `%s`, and prepends all items but the first with the item's position in the array. The function is then applied recursively to every object key and string scalar in the document.

```bash
< my.json jq '
  def f: ./"%s" | [to_entries[][] | numbers |= "%\(.)$s"][1:] | add;
  walk(objects |= with_entries(.key |= f) | strings |= f)
'
```

```json
{
  "Text %1$s and %2$s": "Text2 %1$s or %2$s",
  "Here is \"Name %1$s\" and %2$s and %3$s": "Blabla %1$s and %2$s or %3$s"
}
```

[Demo on jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/flGbsu7k-bB)