# how to find two lines of strings in bash with awk or grep

Tags: bash, awk, grep

This is a sample of `data.txt`:

```
"line1":"text1",
"line2":"text2",
"line3":"text3",
"line4":"text4",
"line5":"text5",
"line6":"text6",
"line7":"text7",
"line8":"text8",
"line9":"text9",
"line10":"text10"
```

This is a very simple data, but I'm trying to do this:

```
file line `"line7":"text7",\n"line8":"text8",` and three lines before that, and save two variables that I can use in my bash:

content_of_line4='text4'
content_of_lint5='text5'
```

What I think can be done is something like this:

```
content_of_line4="$(the_awk_or_grep_command)"
content_of_lint5="$(the_awk_or_grep_command)"
```

What I tried so far:

```
grep -E "\"line7\":\"text7",\n\"line8\":\"text8\"," -B3 data.txt
```

As soon as I add `\n\"line8\":\"text8\",`, the `grep` finds nothing. If I remove this, it shows.

I need to use the two variables in my bash commands in the future, so I need to store them.

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: @Paolo desired output is to store value of those two lines into two different variables. Expected output is that.

Comment: "regular" grep processes data "1 line at a time" - which is why it cannot match a multi-line pattern. Your data looks like JSON? If it is, it would be better to show a full example input/output as there are better tools for that e.g. `jq`

Comment: @jqurious yes, it's a JSON. I'll edit soon with more realistic data.

Comment: Your question actually makes no sense. If you already know the contents of `"line7\":\"text7"` in order to grep it, you can just store that. If this is in fact JSON, post a real example.

Comment: Assuming that you have two *independent* lines and want to have respectively 4 lines before them, I would use two separate `grep` commands. If performance is an issue, I would loop through the file explicitly and print the two resulting lines to stdout. On the calling side, you could then put them into an array (be careful with word splitting!).

Comment: Dear @Saeed , I would greatly appreciate it if you could take the time to review the answers provided and ultimately select one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input *looks like* the "inner part" of a JSON object. If so, you could add the "missing" curly braces, and use jq to extract the fields needed. Example:

```bash
content_of_line4="$(jq -Rsr '"{\(.)}" | fromjson.line4' input.txt)"
echo "$content_of_line4"
```

```
text4
```

---

For better reusability, you can also employ the `--arg` option to use values from the shell for the field name:

```bash
content_of_line5="$(jq -Rsr --arg f "line5" '"{\(.)}" | fromjson[$f]' input.txt)"
echo "$content_of_line5"
```

```
text5
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not trying to only find line number N, but I'm trying to grep two consecutive lines and some lines before them.

Comment: @Saeed You could expand the jq filter to, say, `fromjson | .line4, .line5`, then from the shell use `read` to capture both results into their own variables.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk which supports `gensub()` function, would you please try:

```
#!/bin/bash

l1='"line7":"text7",'                           # target line-1
l2='"line8":"text8",'                           # target line-2 (following the line above)

IFS=$'\t' read -r val1 val2 < <(                # assign bash variables val1 and val2 to the output of awk
awk -v l1="$l1" -v l2="$l2" '                   # feed line-1 and line-2 as awk variables
NR >= 5 && a[(NR - 1) % 4] == l1 && $0 == l2 {
                                                # compare previous line and current line with given variables
    val1 = gensub(/.+:[[:blank:]]*"([^"]+)".*/, "\\1", 1, a[(NR - 4) % 4])
                                                # fetch 4 lines above and extract the value
    val2 = gensub(/.+:[[:blank:]]*"([^"]+)".*/, "\\1", 1, a[(NR - 3) % 4])
                                                # fetch 3 lines above and extract the value
    print val1 "\t" val2                        # print the values delimited by a tab character
}
{
    a[NR % 4] = $0                              # put current record in the ring buffer of size 4
}' data.txt)

echo "$val1"                                    # see bash variables
echo "$val2"
```

Output:

```
text4
text5
```

- As we need to memorize last four lines (excluding current line),
  a ring buffer of size 4 is good enough.
- When accessing the ring buffer, the modulo operator `%` is useful.
- The condition `NR >= 5` skips the first 4 lines because they cannot
  be the candidate of match.
- `gensub(/.+:[[:blank:]]*"([^"]+)".*/, "\\1", 1, a[(NR - 4) % 4])`
  extracts the value surrounded by double quotes after a colon character.
- The output of awk is passed to bash variables via the process substitution
  `IFS=$'\t' read -r val1 val2 < <( awk script )`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can effortlessly resolve this issue by utilizing either grep or awk, employing these two simple scripts:

With Grep

```
#!/bin/bash

#read the JSON file and extract the desired lines
json_file="data.txt"
lines=$(grep -B 3 -A 2 '"line7":"text7",' "$json_file")

#extract the content of line 4 and line 5
content_of_line4=$(echo "$lines" | grep -oE '"line4":"([^"]+)"' | cut -d'"' -f4)
content_of_line5=$(echo "$lines" | grep -oE '"line5":"([^"]+)"' | cut -d'"' -f4)

#print the extracted content for verification
echo "Content of line 4: $content_of_line4"
echo "Content of line 5: $content_of_line5"
```

Or with AWK

```
#!/bin/bash

#read the JSON file and extract the desired lines
json_file="data.txt"
lines=$(awk '/"line7":"text7"/ {print a[NR-3], a[NR-2], a[NR-1], $0} {a[NR]=$0}' "$json_file")

#extract the content of line 4 and line 5
content_of_line4=$(echo "$lines" | awk -F'"' '{print $4}')
content_of_line5=$(echo "$lines" | awk -F'"' '{print $8}')

#print the extracted content for verification
echo "Content of line 4: $content_of_line4"
echo "Content of line 5: $content_of_line5"
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution in [TXR](https://nongnu.org/txr):

```
$ txr extract.txr data
content_of_line4='text4'
content_of_lint5='text5'
```

Where `extract.txr` is:

```
@(skip)
"line4":"@content4",
"line5":"@content5",
@(skip)
"line7":"text7",
"line8":"text8",
@(output)
content_of_line4='@content4'
content_of_lint5='@content5'
@(end)
```

Suppose the labels are arbitrary and we really want to go by line numbers. I.e. get the values from lines 4 and 5, regardless of what the labels are, if lines 7 and 8 have certain values, regardless of their labels:

```
@(skip)
@(line 4)
@nil:"@content4",
@nil:"@content5",
@(skip)
@(line 7)
@nil:"text7",
@nil:"text8",
@(output)
content_of_line4='@content4'
content_of_lint5='@content5'
@(end)
```

A JSON-based solution might look like this. We can turn the individual items into object syntax like `{"line1":"text1"}`, and then put these into a JSON array `[{"line1":"text1"},{"line2":..."}...]` and parse it as JSON. Then take the range of lines from 4 to 8 and do some pattern matching on the objects:

```
(flow "data"
  file-get-lines
  (mapcar (opip (trim-right ",") `{@1}`))
  (join-with ",")
  `[@1]`
  get-json
  (let lines)
  (when-match ^#J[{~nil : ~content4},
                  {~nil : ~content5},
                  ~nil,
                  {~nil : "text7"},
                  {~nil : "text8"}]
              [lines 3..8]
    (put-line `content_of_line4='@content4'\n \
               content_of_lint5='@content5'`)))
```

Run:

```
$ txr jextract.tl
content_of_line4='text4'
content_of_lint5='text5'
```